# How to select only some fields from signIns in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: request, postman, microsoft-graph-api

I am using postman, and I sent this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=startswith(appDisplayName,'Microsoft Teams')&$select=userDisplayName,userPrincipalName,createdDateTime&$top=15
```

The output was:

[image]

The problem occurs only when I use the `select` param.

Do you know how to solve it?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$select is not supported on `/beta/auditlogs/*` or `v1.0/auditLogs` as of this moment.

We will keep you posted once this feature is available.

Comment: Thank you very much.